# DFP Background Skin - can't get it centered

Tags: css

I'm loading a Google DFP background skin ad unit. I've got it showing up correctly, but I cannot get the background image to stay centered once the web browser shrinks to a smaller width than the image width itself. Rather the image gets pegged to the left hand side of the browse and collapses from right to left resulting in the center content panel not being centered on the background image anymore.

My html code is:

```
<div id="background-skin" class="desktop-ad">
<div id='div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXX-X'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXX-X'); });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

The css I use is:

```
#background-skin {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 1600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get to the desired effect is by setting the `fixed` wrapper at 50% horizontally, with `left`, and no width needed. Let it grow with the content:

```
#background-skin {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 1600px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Then, misplace its child by `-50%` using `left` and `position: relative;`. Something like:

```
#background-skin > div {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    ...
```

This way, the container would be in the very middle of the page, and the content would be in the very middle of the container.

[**See this example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pbnrk8p6/1/)